# Roster count on discord.py dysfunctional

Tags: discord.py

When signing a player to a team, bot doesn't print a roster count, and just says 0.

```py
@bengals.event
@commands.has_any_role('Franchise Owner', 'General Manager', 'Head Coach', 'Assistant Coach')
async def on_message(message, *, user:discord.Member=None):
  if '<:Cincinnati_Bengals:801216801425457153> sign' in message.content:
    signee=message.mentions[0].mention
    signeeid=message.mentions[0].id
    guild = bengals.get_guild(801206329049612288)
    bengalrole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Cincinnati Bengals")
    freerole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="✨ League Membership")
    rostercount = len(bengalrole.members)
    embedsigned = discord.Embed(title="KFG Transaction Complete", description=signee+" has been signed to the <:Cincinnati_Bengals:801216801425457153> Cincinnati Bengals.", color = discord.Color.green())
    embedsigned.add_field(name=f'<:Cincinnati_Bengals:801216801425457153> Cincinnati Bengals new roster count is **{rostercount}**.', value="KFG Transaction")
    await message.channel.send(embed=embedsigned)
    for guys in server.members:
        if guys.id==signeeid:
            await guys.add_roles(bengalrole)
            await guys.remove_roles(freerole)
```

[image: Bot says 0 for roster count.]

Comment: make sure you have members intent enabled

Comment: Alright, I enabled that, but now when I run it, it says "Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces as indentation."

Comment: That means that you need to possibly re indent your python code, because you've used spaces and tabs in different places to indent the code. Normally this is supported by IDEs with automatic buttons etc. Atom has it for instance.